# Browser images display incorrectly

Tags: android, html, css, jpeg, gif

Just wondered if anyone knew why my site looks like crap on Android Browsers.

Looks fine on iOS, very occasionally looks ok on certain Android phones but more often than not looks like this:

[looks like crap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heTea.png)

The actual site is [www.macey.3owl.com](http://www.macey.3owl.com) if you visit from desktop or iOS, looks perfect (aside from not 100% finished =))

I got to thinking it might be a timeout problem but I genuinely don't know. Just looks like it's loading everything in 256k or something. Jpegs made in Photoshop and compressed with Easy thumbnails and gifs made with Photoshop.

Any insight would be great.

EDIT: Viewed on an HTC Sensation Z710e and a Nexus 4 in Dolphin HD, Stock Browser and Chrome with same problems in each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why I didn't notice earlier, but thought I'd answer my own question.

It was bloody 3G network compression.

Anyone suffering the same problems can either turn the compression off e.g: [accelerator.orange.co.uk](http://accelerator.orange.co.uk) or you can inline the pictures using [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), you can set the HTTP header to

```
cache-control: no-transform
```

But not all proxies obey that so you can switch to HTTPS or quite simply, like I did, change your images to PNG format.